# When is a smooth point of a projective, simplicial, toric variety $ X_{\Sigma} $ compatibly $ F $-split?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties, frobenius-map, frobenius-splitting

A variety $ X $ is $ F $-split if there exists an $ \mathcal{O}_{X} $-linear map $ \phi: F_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to \mathcal{O}_{X} $ such that $ \phi \circ F^{\sharp} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} $.  Such a map $ \phi $ is called a splitting.  A closed sub-scheme $ Y $ of $ X $ is compatibly split if there exists a splitting $ \phi $ such that $ \phi(F_{\ast}(\mathcal{I}_{Y})) \subseteq \mathcal{I}_{Y} $.  Note that $ \mathcal{I}_{Y} \subseteq \phi(F_{\ast}(\mathcal{I}_{Y})) $ already.

If $ X $ is a normal variety, then $ X $ if $ F $-regular if for all effective Weil divisors $ D $ there is an $ e \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \mathcal{O}_{X} \to F^{e}_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}) \to F^{e}_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)) $ splits.

All toric varieties are $ F $-regular.  Suppose that $ X_{\Sigma} $ is a simplicial, projective, toric variety and that $ Y $ is equal to $ \operatorname{Bl}_{e}(X_{\Sigma}) $ where $ e $ is a smooth point of the torus (we may take it to be the identity of the torus).  If $ e $ splits compatibly with $ X_{\Sigma} $, then it follows that $ \operatorname{Bl}_{e}(X_{\Sigma}) $ should be $ F $-regular.  When is a smooth point of a simplicial, projective, toric variety compatibly split?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head.  I'm sure this isn't true for globally F-regular varieties in general but don't know about toric ones.  By the way, it can happen that the blowup is globally F-regular but the point that was blown up is not compatibly split.  Is that what you really want?